# Can I launch android apps from within my app?

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I' thinking about writing a launch-application, where the user launches his favorite applications from within my app. It would be on mobile devices and made using Action Script (flash or flex). I wonder if this is possible on Android. From what I can see, it is possible on iOS using URL Schemes. Is the process similar on the Android platform? I've seen this question asked before, but not using Action Script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with `schemes` to but I think you'll have to know each apps scheme, and as far as I know you can not retrieve it, and maybe not all apps have schemes implemented.

You should probably use `Intents` which facilitate the communication between different Android applications. You can have a look at [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that. Too bad there's no ready list, easy to access.